# Operations on data frames in the loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have three data frame and I would like to perform some operation on them in the loop (transpose and assign names to columns). The problem with my code is that the data frames are not updated and the result is a completely new data frame.

```
df1 = data.frame(A = c(1, 2), B = c(1, 2))
df2 = data.frame(A = c(1, 2), B = c(1, 2))
df3 = data.frame(A = c(1, 2), B = c(1, 2))

names = c("df1", "df2", "df3")

for(df in names) {
  df = get(names)
  df = t(df)
  colnames(df) = df[1, ]
  df = df[-1, ]
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop only updates `df` object not the originals. Also do be aware: your attempted output is not a dataframe but a matrix which is return of `t()`.

Comment: I just would like to update the original data frames, not `df` object. Thanks for your attention - I will add `as.data.frame()` step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is place all of the dataframes in a list and then work with the list instead of the individual dataframes.

```
df1 = data.frame(A = c(1, 2), B = c(1, 2))
df2 = data.frame(A = c(1, 2), B = c(1, 2))
df3 = data.frame(A = c(1, 2), B = c(1, 2))

names = list(df1, df2, df3)

names<-lapply(names, function(df){
  df = t(df)
  colnames(df) = df[1, ]
  df = df[-1, ]
})
```

Of course the list "names" have then updated dataframes and the original dataframes are untouched.

**EDIT**
In order to address your comment of reducing data redundancy.  I tweaked your code and used the `assign()` function to update the data frames in the global environment.

```
df1 = data.frame(A = c(1, 2), B = c(1, 2))
df2 = data.frame(A = c(1, 2), B = c(1, 2))
df3 = data.frame(A = c(1, 2), B = c(1, 2))

names = c("df1", "df2", "df3")

for(name in names) {
  df = get(name)
  df = t(df)
  colnames(df) = df[1, ]
  df = df[-1, ]
  assign(name, df)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to avoid data redundancy and increase RAM usage.

Comment: The edited answer is completely satisfying, thanks.